# How to keep TextBlock Textname exactly center

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a textblock and assigned its name i kept Text Alignment="Center" the output displays as center in 1st line. . .I want exactly Center so,How Can i adjust?

Comment: I implemented this way: <Canvas Name="cnvMain" Width="400" Height="200" >
               <TextBlock Canvas.Left="111" Canvas.Top="22"  Name="TextBlockName" Height="100" Width="200"></TextBlock>
            </Canvas>

Comment: And In .cs File private void LayOut()
        {
            TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
            double halfwidth = TextBlockName.Width / 2;
            double halfheight = TextBlockName.Height / 2;
            TextBlockName.Width = halfwidth;
            TextBlockName.Height = halfheight;
            TextBlockName.Text = "CustomerDetails";
            
            TextBlockName.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, halfwidth);
            TextBlockName.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, halfheight);
            
        }   But TextBlock Name is not getting. .Can any1 tel me the solution?

Comment: CAn v write any setters?

Comment: Why are you using a Canvas? Try Grid if you need automatic layout.

Comment: k. .then how will set its position center in textblock?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Grid would be easier than a Canvas. For instance you can do:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="My text" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

---

EDIT after discussion:

Here is an example of code adding a text at a specific position in a Canvas:

```
    private void AddText(double x, double y, string textContent)
    {
        var text = new TextBlock()
        {
            Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            Text = textContent
        };
        MyCanvas.Children.Add(text);
        Canvas.SetLeft(text, x);
        Canvas.SetTop(text, y);
    }

// Usage:
AddText(100, 100, "Test");
```

Comment: Ya. .It is displaying in Center in 1st Line but i want to show that name in Exactly Center i.e., in middle line. .Like In Button,The button text should b center like that i have to show. .For Example,my width is 100,height is 100.The Text should start with in width 50,height 50.If i changing my text,The already text should go upside. .Sorry for my english

Comment: Or another example is that in Graph i.e.,In (X,Y)coordinates the origin is in (0,0)position. .In that position i have to set the text and another example is IN ellipse the center point. .

Comment: If you're making a graph program with several labels, you will have to set the position in code, and using Canvas would be right for that.

Comment: ha. But In Code Behind i wrote as 
var width=(TextBlockName.Width)/2 and var height=(TextBlockName.Height)/2 and set in TExtBlockName.Text="Hi customer" But it not working. .and i set padding also But No use. .

Comment: You can't use Height and Width, you have to use ActualHeight and ActualWidth for that kind of thing, except if your height/width are constants.

Comment: Hey jv42,I executed above AddText Method ,It works fine. .But the problem is if i add more words in place of test,the text is moving out of textblock in output. .

Comment: Yes, it's only a starting point. You have to edit it so it takes into account the TextBlock's ActualWidth and ActualHeight.

Comment: Is it possible to set height,width by fixed value?I mean that if v set width,height to some value,After that If v add text then that text shoulb be middle part only i.e.,the text should not go outside. .Thanxs for helping me. .

Comment: Yes, as I said above (except if your height/width are constants). If you set them to hard values (not Auto), you can easily center them, but you'll have to be sure this doesn't result in text clipping (shortened).

Comment: <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
                <Border x:Name="Text" BorderBrush="CadetBlue" Height="200" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="298">
                <TextBlock  Name="TextBlockName" Height="172" Width="200" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="hiiiiiiiii">
                </TextBlock>             
             </Border>
        </Canvas> and in .cs file i write as AddText(200,220,"Sme Long text"); that time the text is not displaying properly. .Can u share whole code if possible. .